# Cannot compile program-exits with code 1

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, computer-vision

I am using opencv,c++ and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 to compile my code but I get all these.

```
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\herohuyongtao\Debug\herohuyongtao.exe', Symbols loaded.
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_core242d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10\tbb_debug.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_highgui242d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avifil32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avicap32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_imgproc242d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_objdetect242d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'herohuyongtao.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

and finally it says

```
The program '[6728] herohuyongtao.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Apparenly these are not errors.I tried several solutions but no results. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the program? Stepping through it to see why that happens?

Comment: Your program is compiled or you wouldn't be able to run it in the debugger.  Post your main function at least.

Comment: The "cannot find or open the PDB file" comments just means MSVC can't load debugging information for the specified files. It's usually not a big deal, since those are mostly system libraries.

Comment: I would have put the code in the question but it's too long. Here it is http://pastebin.com/WKYvVKDx. I am now doing a stepping through the code.

Comment: I see my name everywhere!!! :P

Comment: oops :p sorry,actually I named the folder as this because I was putting ur code in this empty project and then tried the other example.I forgot to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion, it turned out the code was not receiving the parameters it needed. The code needs these parameters:

```
input output width height
```

`input` is an input video or "" to use the webcam. `output` is an output video file. `width` and `height` are the width and height of the camera frame.

So this should work as intended:

```
"" "myOutputVideo.avi" "320" "240"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cannot compile program-exits with code 1
```

This is a wrong statement. Your program compiles successfully. But when you launch it executes and exits with the code 1. You need to put breakpoints and go through the program to see where it exits.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as a comment than an answer?

Comment: If there's insufficient information to answer the question properly, there's no other choice imo. And OP has now posted the code, which means a proper answer is now possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has several potential `exit` points with a return code of 1, but there's one in particular that strikes me:

```
//int main( int argc, char** argv )
if (argc == 1)
{
    exit(1);
}
```

Since the other `exit` calls have `printf` calls before them, and the sample output in your original question has no output matching those `printf` calls, I'm guessing this particular (silent) `exit` call is responsible. How many parameters are you passing your program?

Comment: okay I commented this if part and the console window appears with "Structure model loaded in 23s". The program is supposed to activate my webcam. The error is apparently found on line 218 because there was a yellow arrow there

Comment: I *really* think you need to see how many parameters you're passing your program. A lot of your setup code is `argc`-dependent: there's code conditional on `argc > 1`, `argc > 2`, and `argc > 4`. If you're not passing enough parameters, I think a lot of your setup code is likely to break. In particular, I'm guessing `argc == 1` (hence your silent `exit`) and therefore your `frame` is never being set up.

Comment: the webcam will need to extract the frame,its width and height. So,I think these will be its parameters. I really do not see any error in the code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenCV so I can't comment much on the code itself, but if you're not passing the parameters the code seems to expect, I don't think it'll work correctly. Try passing it an input filename, an output filename, a width, and a height and see what happens.

Comment: I'm referring to the program itself, in case that wasn't clear, not the webcam. `argv` stores the parameters the program itself is passed when you run it. `argc` stores the number of parameters you passed. With this in mind, your errors make a lot more sense.

Comment: No, when you start the program it expects certain parameters, and at the moment it doesn't appear you're providing those. (It's possible I'm using different terminology than you're expecting - what I'm referring to is also known as arguments or command-line flags.)

Comment: I downloaded this code and the necessary files and expected it to work. I understand what you are trying to say but I dont know how many arguments is being passed to command line. I am at a complete loss

Comment: Right now, 0 command-line arguments are being passed to your program. Your code actually tried to tell you that: the `if (argc == 1)` line evaluated to true. This means there's just one command-line parameter, which is the name of your program. You will need to manually specify the parameters you want to pass.

Comment: i really appreciate your help!!but I do not understand why I need to change the code,it is supposed to be a workable and tested version. Plus I wont know what parameters to pass. I better use something else to detect the face features

Comment: You *don't* need to change the code. You just need to feed it the command-line parameters it wants. And assuming I read the code correctly, I listed the parameters it needs earlier: an input filename, an output filename, a width, and a height, in that order.

Comment: For example, `myInputVideo.avi myOutputVideo.avi 400 200` would tell the code to read from `myInputVideo.avi`, use `myOutputVideo.avi` as the output file, and set the camera frame to 400x200 (probably px). That's all you need to do. The code itself should be fine.